# How do I access the router in a Vue 3 Functional component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to add a simple functional component that will prefill my Pinia store with random data and route back to the home page. I tried `useRouter` but the value is undefined.

```
import { FunctionalComponent } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useUserProfileStore } from "./stores/UserProfile";

const Prefill: FunctionalComponent<{}> = (props, { slots, emit, attrs }) => {
  const userProfileStore = useUserProfileStore();
  const router = useRouter();
  userProfileStore.randomData();
  router.replace("/"); // but router is undefined?
};
Prefill.props = [];
Prefill.emits = [];
export default Prefill;
```

I defined my route as

```
    {
      path: "/cheat",
      name: "Prefill",
      component: Prefill,
    },
```

Comment: You seem to misuse functional component. Its body is what runs on every render. It's not supposed to contain side effects, and certainly not like router navigation because this could result in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Mehdi's answer but instead of `inject("$router")` I used the actual router instance.

Mehdi's answer is fails type checks.

```
import { FunctionalComponent } from "vue";
import { router } from "./router";
import { useUserProfileStore } from "./stores/UserProfile";

const Prefill: FunctionalComponent = () => {
  const userProfileStore = useUserProfileStore();
  userProfileStore.randomData();
  router.replace("/");
};
Prefill.props = [];
Prefill.emits = [];
export default Prefill;
```

With this approach I can add to the router configuration

```
{
  path: "/prefill",
  name: "Prefill",
  component: Prefill,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional components are stateless and the don't do any side effects, but they can emit events fired by interacting with component element :

```js
import { FunctionalComponent } from "vue";

const Prefill: FunctionalComponent<{}> = (props, { slots, emit, attrs }) => {
 
//somewhere in the render function/jsx do
  emit('goto','/')
 
};
Prefill.props = [];
Prefill.emits = ["goto"];
export default Prefill;
```

in parent component :

```html
<Prefill @goto="(path)=>$router.push(path)" .../>
```

Comment: with this approach, how do you add the route the FC in the route configuration?

Comment: I cannot understand your question

Comment: Say I want the component to be used as the component in a route.  how do I pass the event handlers?  You can see my answer